# JS PHP Fetch not passing values

Tags: javascript, php, sql, json, fetch-api

I'm being an idiot again and can't seem to get a PHP function to accept data from js. The PHP class appears to be working to some extent as the getTopFive() function works elsewhere in this application, however I can't seem to get data insertion working. Code is as follows (I have also included a fetch payload with redacted info for reference)

```js
    function sSc(currentScore, uid, username, avatar) {
    console.log(currentScore, uid, username, avatar);
    fetch('phplib/data.class.php', {
        "method": 'POST',
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": JSON.stringify({
            action: 'handleRequest',
            uid: uid,
            username: username,
            avatar: avatar,
            score: currentScore
        })
    }).then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
        console.log(response);
    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data); // Output received from the PHP file after processing the request
        // You can perform any additional actions here after the score is submitted.
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Failed to submit the score");
        console.log(error);
        // You can handle errors here if the score submission fails.
    });
}
```

this code produces requests that look like this:
{"action":"handleRequest","uid":"12345","username":"uname","avatar":"https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/12345/12345.png","score":0}

The full PHP class is as follows:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('db.class.php');



class Scores{

private static $db;
private $sql, $stmt;

public function __construct(){
    self::$db = db::getInstance();
    $this->handleRequest();
}

private function handleRequest() {
    // Check if the fetch request contains the 'action' parameter
    if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'handleRequest') {
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

        // Create an instance of the Scores class
        $scores = new Scores();

        // Call the insertData() method to insert the data into the database
        $result = $scores->insertData($data['avatar'], $data['uid'], $data['username'], $data['score']);

        // Send a response back to the frontend
        // You can customize the response based on the result of the insert operation.
        // For example:
        if ($result) {
            echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'message' => 'Data inserted successfully.']);
        } else {
            echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Failed to insert data.']);
        }
    } else {
        // Handle missing data parameters or invalid action if necessary.
        echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Invalid action.']);
    }
}




public function getData($style = MYSQLI_ASSOC) {
    $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM highscores order by score DESC limit 10;";
    $this->stmt = self::$db->prepare($this->sql);
    $this->stmt->execute();
    $result = $this->stmt->get_result();
    $resultset=$result->fetch_all($style);
    return $resultset;
}

public function getScore($uid, $style = MYSQLI_ASSOC) {
    $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM highscores WHERE uid = ?;";
    $this->stmt = self::$db->prepare($this->sql);
    $this->stmt->bind_param("s",$uid);
    $this->stmt->execute();
    $result = $this->stmt->get_result();
    $resultset=$result->fetch_all($style);
    return $resultset;
}

public function getTopFive($style = MYSQLI_ASSOC) {
    $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM highscores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5;";
    $this->stmt = self::$db->prepare($this->sql);
    $this->stmt->execute();
    $result = $this->stmt->get_result();
    $resultset = $result->fetch_all($style);
    return json_encode($resultset);
}



public function insertData($avatar, $uid, $username, $score) {
    // Check if the user's current score is higher than the one in the database
    echo "insertData";
    $highestScore = $this->getHighestScore($uid);

    if ($score > $highestScore) {
        $this->sql = "INSERT INTO highscores (uid, username, avatar, score) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score=VALUES(score), avatar=VALUES(avatar), username=VALUES(username);";
        $this->stmt = self::$db->prepare($this->sql);

        // Bind parameters
        $this->stmt->bind_param("sssi", $uid, $username, $avatar, $score);

        // Execute the query and handle errors
        try {
            $this->stmt->execute();

            // Log success message to the browser console
            echo '<script>';
            echo 'console.log("Data inserted successfully.");';
            echo '</script>';

            return true; // Insertion successful
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Log error message to the browser console
            echo '<script>';
            echo 'console.error("Error inserting data: ' . $e->getMessage() . '");';
            echo '</script>';

            return false; // Insertion failed
        }
    }

    /*
    $this->sql = "INSERT INTO highscores (uid, username, avatar, score) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score=VALUES(score), avatar=VALUES(avatar), username=VALUES(username);";
    $this->stmt = self::$db->prepare($this->sql);

    // Bind parameters
    $this->stmt->bind_param("sssi", $uid, $username, $avatar, $score);

    // Execute the query and handle errors
    try {
        $this->stmt->execute();

        // Log success message to the browser console
        echo '<script>';
        echo 'console.log("Data inserted successfully.");';
        echo '</script>';

        return true; // Insertion successful
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Log error message to the browser console
        echo '<script>';
        echo 'console.error("Error inserting data: ' . $e->getMessage() . '");';
        echo '</script>';

        return false; // Insertion failed
    }
    */
    return false; // The score was not updated
}



private function getHighestScore($uid) {
    $this->sql = "SELECT MAX(score) as highest_score FROM highscores WHERE uid = ?;";
    $this->stmt = self::$db->prepare($this->sql);
    $this->stmt->bind_param("s", $uid);
    $this->stmt->execute();
    $result = $this->stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    return isset($row['highest_score']) ? (int) $row['highest_score'] : 0;
}
}

?>
```

EDIT This is the full index.php, the getTopFive call works so the data.class.php calls db.class.php correctly

Index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="./Box2dWeb-2.1.a.3.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha384-vtXRMe3mGCbOeY7l30aIg8H9p3GdeSe4IFlP6G8JMa7o7lXvnz3GFKzPxzJdPfGK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/easeljs.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/preloadjs.min.js" defer></script>
    <title>Assessment 1</title>
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);    
    require_once('OAuth.class.php');
    require_once('phplib/data.class.php');
    $scores = new Scores();
    $highscores = $scores->getTopFive();
    $handler = new ProviderHandler();
    $handler->performAction();
    ?>
    <?php
    if ($handler->status == 'logged in') {
        echo '<script>console.log("Logged in");</script>';
        $scripthtml = '<script>"use strict"; let myusername="' . $handler->providerInstance->getName() . '";
        let myuserid="' . $handler->providerInstance->getUserID() . '";
        let avatar="' . $handler->providerInstance->getAvatar() . '";var paused=true; </script>';
        echo $scripthtml;
    } else {
        echo '<script>console.log("Not logged in");</script>';
        ?>
        <script>
        'use strict';
        let myusername="";
        let myuserid="";
        let avatar="";
        var paused=true;
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    <script src="./main.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    if ($handler->status == 'logged out' || $handler->status == null) {
        echo $handler->generateLoginText();
    } else {
        echo $handler->generateLogout();
        echo '<h1>' . $handler->providerInstance->getName() . '</h1>';
        echo '<img src="' . $handler->providerInstance->getAvatar() . '">';
    }
    ?>

<main id="main">
    <div id ="splash">
        <h1>Downfall</h1>
        <h2>By Harry Main</h2>
    </div>
    <div id ="levelselect">
            <label for="level">Level:</label>
            <select id="level">
                <option value="1">Earth</option>
                <option value="2">Mars</option>
                <option value="3">Venus</option>
                <option value="4">Kepler 452b</option>
                <option value="5">Kepler 22b</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    <div id ="game">Game 
        <div id="gametext">
            <h3 id="score">Score: 0 </h3>
            <h3 id="health">Health: 5 </h3>
            <h3 id="alt">Altitude: 100000 </h3>
        </div> 
        <button id="startStopButton">Start/Stop</button>
    <canvas id="easelcan" width="1920" height="1080px" ></canvas>
    <canvas id="b2dcan" width="1920" height="1080px"></canvas>           
    </div>
    <div id ="gameover">
        <h1 id=end>Game Over</h1>
        <h2>Score: <span id="finalscore"></span></h2>
        <button id="restartButton">Restart</button>
        <button id="menuButton">Menu</button>
        <button id="nextLevelButton">Next Level</button>
    </div>
    <div id ="hiscores" onload="getHiSc()">
        <button id="highscoreButton">Highscores</button>
        <h1>Highscores</h1>
        <table id="highscoretable">
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Avatar</th>
                <th>Score</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id = "about">About</div>
</main>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("highscoreButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
        getHiSc();
    });

    document.getElementById("restartButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
        sSc(currentScore, myuserid, myusername, avatar);
    });

    function subScore(currentScore, uid, username, avatar) {
    console.log(currentScore, uid, username, avatar);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'phplib/data.class.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'insertData',
            uid: uid,
            username: username,
            avatar: avatar,
            score: currentScore
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data); // Output received from the PHP file after processing the request
            // You can perform any additional actions here after the score is submitted.
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("Failed to submit the score");
            // You can handle errors here if the score submission fails.
        }
    });
}




// Function to fill the highscores table
function fillHighscores(highscores) {
    var table = document.getElementById("highscoretable");
    console.log("Received highscores:", highscores);


    // Clear existing high scores from the table (if any)
    while (table.rows.length > 1) {
        table.deleteRow(1);
    }

    // Loop through the highscores object and add each score as a new row in the table.
    for (var i = 0; i < highscores.length; i++) {
        console.log("Processing highscore", i + 1, ":", highscores[i]);
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        var usernameCell = row.insertCell(0);
        var avatarCell = row.insertCell(1);
        var scoreCell = row.insertCell(2);

        avatarCell.innerHTML = '<img src="' + highscores[i].avatar + '">';
        usernameCell.innerHTML = highscores[i].username;
        scoreCell.innerHTML = highscores[i].score;
        }
    }

    function getHiSc() {
        <?php $highscores = $scores->getTopFive(); ?>
        var highscores = <?php echo $highscores; ?>; 
        fillHighscores(highscores);
    }

    function sSc(currentScore, uid, username, avatar) {
    console.log(currentScore, uid, username, avatar);
    fetch('phplib/data.class.php', {
        "method": 'POST',
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": JSON.stringify({
            action: 'handleRequest',
            uid: uid,
            username: username,
            avatar: avatar,
            score: currentScore
        })
    }).then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
        console.log(response);
    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data); // Output received from the PHP file after processing the request
        // You can perform any additional actions here after the score is submitted.
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Failed to submit the score");
        console.log(error);
        // You can handle errors here if the score submission fails.
    });
}


    
</script>

<?php
    var_dump($highscores);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

updated data.class.php:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('db.class.php');

class Scores{

    private static $db;
    private $sql, $stmt;

    public function __construct(){
        self::$db = db::getInstance();
        $this->handleRequest();
    }

    private function handleRequest() {
        // Check if the fetch request contains the 'action' parameter
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
            $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    
            // Create an instance of the Scores class
            $scores = new Scores();
    
            // Call the insertData() method to insert the data into the database
            $result = $scores->insertData($data['avatar'], $data['uid'], $data['username'], $data['score']);
    
            // Send a response back to the frontend
            // You can customize the response based on the result of the insert operation.
            // For example:
            if ($result) {
                echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'message' => 'Data inserted successfully.']);
            } else {
                echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Failed to insert data.']);
            }
        } else {
            // Handle missing data parameters or invalid action if necessary.
            echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Invalid action.']);
        }
    }
    
    
    

    public function getData($style = MYSQLI_ASSOC) {
        $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM highscores order by score DESC limit 10;";
        $this->stmt = self::$db->prepare($this->sql);
        $this->stmt->execute();
        $result = $this->stmt->get_result();
        $resultset=$result->fetch_all($style);
        return $resultset;
    }

    public function getScore($uid, $style = MYSQLI_ASSOC) {
        $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM highscores WHERE uid = ?;";
        $this->stmt = self::$db->prepare($this->sql);
        $this->stmt->bind_param("s",$uid);
        $this->stmt->execute();
        $result = $this->stmt->get_result();
        $resultset=$result->fetch_all($style);
        return $resultset;
    }

    public function getTopFive($style = MYSQLI_ASSOC) {
        $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM highscores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5;";
        $this->stmt = self::$db->prepare($this->sql);
        $this->stmt->execute();
        $result = $this->stmt->get_result();
        $resultset = $result->fetch_all($style);
        return json_encode($resultset);
    }
    


    public function insertData($avatar, $uid, $username, $score) {
        // Check if the user's current score is higher than the one in the database
        echo "insertData";
        $highestScore = $this->getHighestScore($uid);

        if ($score > $highestScore) {
            $this->sql = "INSERT INTO highscores (uid, username, avatar, score) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score=VALUES(score), avatar=VALUES(avatar), username=VALUES(username);";
            $this->stmt = self::$db->prepare($this->sql);

            // Bind parameters
            $this->stmt->bind_param("sssi", $uid, $username, $avatar, $score);

            // Execute the query and handle errors
            try {
                $this->stmt->execute();

                // Log success message to the browser console
                echo '<script>';
                echo 'console.log("Data inserted successfully.");';
                echo '</script>';

                return true; // Insertion successful
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // Log error message to the browser console
                echo '<script>';
                echo 'console.error("Error inserting data: ' . $e->getMessage() . '");';
                echo '</script>';

                return false; // Insertion failed
            }
        }

        /*
        $this->sql = "INSERT INTO highscores (uid, username, avatar, score) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score=VALUES(score), avatar=VALUES(avatar), username=VALUES(username);";
        $this->stmt = self::$db->prepare($this->sql);

        // Bind parameters
        $this->stmt->bind_param("sssi", $uid, $username, $avatar, $score);

        // Execute the query and handle errors
        try {
            $this->stmt->execute();

            // Log success message to the browser console
            echo '<script>';
            echo 'console.log("Data inserted successfully.");';
            echo '</script>';

            return true; // Insertion successful
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Log error message to the browser console
            echo '<script>';
            echo 'console.error("Error inserting data: ' . $e->getMessage() . '");';
            echo '</script>';

            return false; // Insertion failed
        }
        */
        return false; // The score was not updated
    }

    

    private function getHighestScore($uid) {
        $this->sql = "SELECT MAX(score) as highest_score FROM highscores WHERE uid = ?;";
        $this->stmt = self::$db->prepare($this->sql);
        $this->stmt->bind_param("s", $uid);
        $this->stmt->execute();
        $result = $this->stmt->get_result();
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

        return isset($row['highest_score']) ? (int) $row['highest_score'] : 0;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The JSON output is from console logging; or that is the payload inside `body`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are sending data as JSON, the $_POST never contains any keys, so:

```php
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'handleRequest')
```

is never satisfied.

You can use:

```php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
```

and / or decode the *php://input* and test it's content:

```php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
if (($data['action'] ?? NULL) === 'handleRequest')
```

##### ADDENDUM FOR *"Unexpected end of JSON input"* ERROR

The error *"Unexpected end of JSON input"* seems to be a different problem.
In the newly posted code the line *140* corresponds to an empty line, I can suppose that you have made some tests adding some lines.
The nearest line that can cause that error is

```php
console.log("Received highscores:", highscores);
```

contained in the `function fillHighscores(highscores)`,
so if the parameter *highscores* is wrongly filled, that error can happen.
The *function fillHighscores()* is called by the *function getHiSc()*
that I report down here:

```php
function getHiSc() {
   <?php $highscores = $scores->getTopFive(); ?>
   var highscores = <?php echo $highscores; ?>;
   fillHighscores(highscores);
}
```

I suggest you to test the content of the variable *highscores* before calling *fillHighscores()* to make sure it contains a correct value, like so:

```php
var highscores = <?php echo $highscores; ?>;

console.log ("highscores content:", highscores);

fillHighscores(highscores);
```

---

Note also that when you call the *function sSc()*:

```js
document.getElementById("restartButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
        sSc(currentScore, myuserid, myusername, avatar);
});
```

the *currentScore* variable seems to be undefined

Moreover the *data.class.php* when called by the *$.ajax*, apparently can't respond anything, because nothing seems to instantiate the *class Scores*

---

#### More information after some details provided in the comments

Since you say that the line causing the error is the one that corresponds to:

```js
then(function (response) {
   return response.json();  // <-- THIS LINE
   console.log(response);
})
```

in the *function sSc()*, the diagnosis is that the JSON received in the AJAX call is malformed. You can move the *console.log()* before the *return* to debug the response received (in the acutual position it will never be executed)

Comment: Thanks for your responce, I've tried your solution but what I'm getting now is the following:
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at index.php:140:25
relating to the return response.json and the data is still not entered into the system.

Comment: you should post all the code  involved

Comment: Edited the original question to show the current updated code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @HarryMain I have updated my answer adding some information about the probable cause of the error

Comment: double checked, line 140 references the   return response.json(); part of the sSc function

Comment: for reference response looks like this:
Response {type: 'basic', url: '*hostsite*/phplib/data.class.php?action=handleRequest', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}

Comment: If you copy/paste in an editor the code that you have added in your answer and you go to line 140 you land to the line before the comment `// Clear existing high scores from the table (if any)` - you can try it yourself. The `return response.json();` is at line 181. - I will add some considerations in my answer